# Giving away $500$ pencils: $1$ on the first day, $2$ on the second day, etc. How long will it take?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, puzzle

I'd like to know the name of this subject so that I discover how to solve the problem on my own.

I suppose that's something like "$(n-1) + (n-2) + \cdots$" but I'm not sure about it. =\

> I have 500 pencils and I want to give them to a friend, but not at once. I intend to give one pencil on first day; two on second one; three on third; and so on.
>
> How long will it take to give all pencils? In the end, will remain any pencils?

I appreciate the support!

Comment: It's called "the sum of an arithmetic progression".

Comment: Yes! Thank you, @GerryMyerson :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After $n$ days, you have given
$$1+2+3+\dots n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$
We are looking for the smallest integer $n$ such that 
$$\frac{n(n+1)}2\geq500$$
Since 
$$\frac{31(31+1)}2=496 \quad\text{and}\quad\frac{32(32+1)}2=528$$
You'll give your last pencil on the 32th day, but you'll only give 4 pencils on the last Day.

Comment: Great, @Alain! It helped me a lot! Now I know the name of the subject and how to solve  other problems like this too! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $500 = \frac{days^2}{2}$ since however many pencils recieved on the last day, if you take half of that that will be the average you received each day over the entire time period.